# Restlet - JUnit - testing MULTIPART_FORM_DATA form Post

Tags: junit, restlet

I was wondering what the best way to use JUnit to test a Resource for a Form post?

On a @Get I get service values via a Resource with the following:

```
@Test
public void testGetCollections() throws Exception {
    String url ="http://localhost:14502/api/v1/collections";
    Client client = new Client(Protocol.HTTP);
    ChallengeResponse challengeResponse = new ChallengeResponse(ChallengeScheme.HTTP_BASIC,"user", "f399b0a660f684b2c5a6b4c054f22d89");

    Request request = new Request(Method.GET, url);
    request.setChallengeResponse(challengeResponse);
    Response response = client.handle(request);

    System.out.println("request"+response.getStatus().getCode());
    System.out.println("request test::"+response.getEntityAsText());

    assertEquals(200, response.getStatus().getCode());

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    List<Collection> collectionList = mapper.readValue(response.getEntityAsText(), new TypeReference<List<Collection>>(){});

    for(Collection collection : collectionList){
        System.out.println("TITLE: "+collection.getTitle());
    }

    assertTrue(collectionList.size()>0);
}
```

On the @Post I'm trying to do the following:

```
@Test
public void testPostCollections() throws Exception {
    String url ="http://localhost:14502/api/v1/collections";
    Client client = new Client(Protocol.HTTP);
    ChallengeResponse challengeResponse = new ChallengeResponse(ChallengeScheme.HTTP_BASIC,"user", "f399b0a660f684b2c5a6b4c054f22d89");

    Request request =  new Request(Method.POST, url);
    ClientInfo info = new ClientInfo(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    info.getAcceptedMediaTypes().add(
            new Preference<MediaType>(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    request.setClientInfo(info);

    request.setEntity(
            "collectionName=testCollection123&collectionDescription=testCollectionDescription123",
            MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
     request.setChallengeResponse(challengeResponse);

    Response response = client.handle(request);
    //boolean valid = false;

    System.out.println("request"+response.getStatus().getCode());
    System.out.println("request test::"+response.getEntityAsText());

    assertEquals(200, response.getStatus().getCode());

}
```

I'm getting the following 500 error:
The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request.

BASED ON THE BELOW POSTED ANSWER I MADE THE FOLLOWING WORKING METHOD:

```
@Test
public void testAssetsPost() throws Exception {
    ClientResource cr = new ClientResource("http://localhost:14502/api/v1/ass");

    FormDataSet fds = new FormDataSet();
    fds.getEntries().add(new FormData("metaData", "metaDataTest123"));

    fds.setMultipart(true);
    FormData fileRep = new FormData("file",
            new FileRepresentation(new File("/Users/og/Documents/gump.jpg"),
                    MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG));
    fds.getEntries().add(fileRep);
    FormData fileRep2 = new FormData("associatedDoc",
            new FileRepresentation(new File("/Users/og/Documents/gump.jpg"),
                    MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG));
    fds.getEntries().add(fileRep2);
    Representation r = null;
    try{
        r = cr.post(fds);
    } catch (ResourceException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    System.out.println( "Got Context: " + cr.getContext() );
    System.out.println( "Got Response: " + cr.getResponse());
    System.out.println( "Got Resonse Attribute : " + cr.getResponseAttributes() );
    System.out.println( "Got Resonse Entity: " + cr.getResponseEntity() );
    System.out.println("Got response !! , response : " + r.getText());

    System.out.println(r.getText());

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what is exactly the error you encountered within your server application. I would be interesting if we could have a stacktrace.

That said, you can build programmatically HTML forms using the org.restlet.ext.html extension. For more details, you could read this blog post: http://restlet.com/blog/2015/10/27/implementing-file-upload-with-restlet-framework/.

At a first sight, the media type isn't correct since you don't send a multipart form but a simple form. So you should use `MediaType.APPLICATION_WWW_FORM` instead of `MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA`.

A sample for a form containing a file:

```
Form fileForm = new Form();
fileForm.add(Disposition.NAME_FILENAME, "myimage.png");
Disposition disposition = new Disposition(Disposition.TYPE_INLINE, fileForm);
FileRepresentation entity = new FileRepresentation(f, MediaType.IMAGE_PNG);
entity.setDisposition(disposition);
```

And for a simple form:

```
FormDataSet fds = new FormDataSet();
fds.setMultipart(true);
FormData fdFile = new FormData("fileToUpload", entity);
fds.getEntries().add(fdFile);
FormData fdValue = new FormData("field", "value");
fds.getEntries().add(fdValue);
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Thank you I made an example with 1 parameter and to file parameters and edited my answer at the bottom.